# How to change AWT Label Font

Tags: java, fonts, awt

I am trying to define the Font for an AWT Label.

While I can manage to use fonts for a Java2D graphics environment, same font seems not to work with AWT Labels. I would like to understand if there is any limitation on font usage I am not aware about it for AWT Labels, or if I am simply not using the right syntax/procedure.

this is my code, it basically adds a Label and text to the graphics context:

```java
package com.company.test;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Label;

public class TestTest extends Frame {

    Label myLabel = new Label();
    Font myFont = new Font("Roboto Condensed Light", Font.PLAIN, 12);
    Graphics2D g2d;

    public TestTest() {

        setSize(500,200);
        setLocation(10,10);
        setUndecorated(false);

        myLabel.setBackground(Color.red);
        myLabel.setFont(myFont);
        myLabel.setText("ROBOTO CONDENSED, THIS DOES NOT WORK!");
        add(myLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setVisible(true);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0.0f));

        g2d.setFont(myFont);
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawString("ROBOTO CONDENSED THIS WORKS!",50, 50);

    }


    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        TestTest window = new TestTest();

    }

}
```

This is the result:

[image: Font usage]

While font is properly defined (as it is used in the Text element in the Graphics component), it is not being applied to the AWT Label component.

Any tip is welcomed.

Note: please do not suggest to use SWING or JavaFX, I am well aware that they are the recommended way of using widgets. Question is specifically related to AWT Label widget.

Answer (score 1):

Ok you have to create your own label; the idea is to get to the graphics of things. I have added my inline class but you can create a proper class; then you have to pass the string or other parameters to that class:

```
class TestTest extends Frame {

Font myFont = new Font("Rockwell Nova", Font.PLAIN, 12);
Graphics2D g2d;

public TestTest() {

  Label myLabel = new Label() {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
      g.setFont(myFont);
      g.drawString("ROBOTO CONDENSED, THIS DOES NOT WORK!", 0, 20);
    }
  };
    setSize(500,200);
    setLocation(10,10);
    setUndecorated(false);

    myLabel.setBackground(Color.red);

    add(myLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setVisible(true);

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0.0f));

    g2d.setFont(myFont);
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2d.drawString("ROBOTO CONDENSED THIS WORKS!",50, 50);

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It is a bit discouraging though to have to create your own component, what is .setFont method used for then?

Comment: I see and I agree